# Defining a differential for quotients

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f \colon M \to N$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds and $f$ being a surjective submersion. Assuming we have a proper Lie-group action $G$ on $M$, with only one orbit type and $G$ acts on $N$ also proper. Furthermore let $f$ be $G$-equivariant.

We can now consider the quotientmap

$f' \colon M/G \to N/G$.

Is it now possible to define a differential
$d_{[x]}f' \colon T_{[x]} (M/G) \to T_{f'([x])} (N/G)$?

Edit:
Well, since $M$ has only one orbit-type, we know, that $M/G$ has a manifold structure. If $x\in M$ is such, that there is a subset $U \subset N$ around $f(x)$ and such that for all $y \in U$, the isotropy-group $G_y$ is conjugate to $G_{f(x)}$, then $U/G$ has also a manifold structure and I don't see any problem defining the differential. 
So my question is more, what's happening in $x\in M$ such that $G\cdot f(x)$ is not the principal orbit in $N$.